# Writing Faster Mathematica Code - Sow and Reap?

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering, sow-reap

I am applying `Select` function to a large list called `xyCoordinateCentreCircle`.

The dimensions of the list are:

```
Dimensions[xyCoordinateCentreCircle]
(* {197796, 3} *)
```

All the other variables used in code below are single values.

I am using the following line of code.

```
gridmean = 
  ParallelTable[
   Mean[Last /@ 
     Select[xyCoordinateCentreCircle, 
      z <= #[[1]] <= z + dz && x <= #[[2]] <= x + dx &]], {z, minZ , 
    minZ + dz*(GridSpacingDivisionZ - 1), dz}, {x, minX , 
    minX + dx*(GridSpacingDivisionX - 1), dx}];
```

I have parallelized table to increase speed - still very slow.

I notice this blog (read tip 7):  http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/

Is the function `Last` slow, for the same reason `AppendTo` (read tip 7) is slow?

In which case, could I use `Sow` and `Reap` instead of `Last`? Or is there another reason (possibly use of `Select`)? If you could write an example that would be great.

Following advise from Mike, I've added some numbers...

`xyCoordinateCentreCircle` (sample only, as too  many numbers, Z and X vary unevenly but always increasing, see dimensions at top of post)

```
xyCoordinateCentreCircle = {{5163, 11872, -1228}, {5163, 12640, -1146}, {5163,
```

12672, -1144}, {5163, 12800, -1137}, {5163, 12832, -1136}, {5163, 
  12864, -1139}, {5163, 12896, -1142}, {5163, 12928, -1139}, {5163, 
  12960, -1137}, {5163, 12992, -1137}, {5163, 13024, -1134}, {5163, 
  13056, -1129}, << 197772 >>, {20970, 12864, -1050}, {20970, 12896, -1052}, {20970,
   12928, -1051}, {20970, 12960, -1050}, {20970, 
  12992, -1050}, {20970, 13024, -1050}, {20970, 13056, -1048}, {20970,
   13088, -1049}, {20970, 13120, -1048}, {20970, 
  13152, -1049}, {20970, 13184, -1050}, {20970, 13216, -1052}}

```
Dimensions[gridmean]
(* {15, 16}

gridmean = {{Mean[{}], Mean[{}], Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}], -1179.28, -1108.68, -1089.9, -1084.37, -1077.63, \
-1074.41, -1073.45, -1070.65, -1078.52, Mean[{}], Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}]}, {Mean[{}], Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}], -1117.45, -1101.15, -1086.7, -1081.24, -1075.97, \
-1071.45, -1068.16, -1063.15, -1059.36, -1055.48, -1063.79, -1070.02, 
  Mean[{}]}, {Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}], -1123.93, -1097.66, -1089.47, -1083.27, -1079.06, \
-1074.04, -1069.73, -1065.79, -1060.3, -1057.05, -1051.91, -1054., \
-1046.89, -1058.53}, {Mean[{}], -1124.22, -1100.1, -1092.29, \
-1086.75, -1082.1, -1077.02, -1072.23, -1067.28, -1064.27, -1058.62, \
-1054.72, -1048.92, -1046.88, -1041.33, -1042.94}, {-1200.63, \
-1109.53, -1092.68, -1090.71, -1083.95, -1080.54, -1074.62, -1070.63, \
-1065.49, -1062.8, -1057., -1053.41, -1048.23, -1048.28, -1039.07, \
-1035.35}, {-1123.35, -1097.05, -1091.21, -1088.95, -1081.91, \
-1078.57, -1073.07, -1068.8, -1063.64, -1061.76, -1055.51, -1052.07, \
-1046.89, -1046.12, -1037.53, -1032.99}, {-1107.77, -1095.25, \
-1089.34, -1087.53, -1080.67, -1076.12, -1071.44, -1067.36, -1061.88, \
-1060.29, -1054.07, -1050.75, -1045.05, -1044.69, -1036.46, \
-1031.18}, {-1102.98, -1092.99, -1087.24, -1085.36, -1079.45, -1075., \
-1070.57, -1065.88, -1060.48, -1058.94, -1052.8, -1049.19, -1044.1, \
-1042.64, -1035.08, -1029.88}, {-1095.54, -1090.84, -1086.89, \
-1081.99, -1078.71, -1073.36, -1068.81, -1064.28, -1058.86, -1057.36, \
-1051.76, -1047.39, -1043.11, -1040.75, -1033.29, -1027.76}, \
{-1092.51, -1088.1, -1085.65, -1080.34, -1077.43, -1072.06, -1067.56, \
-1063.29, -1057.48, -1055.33, -1050.53, -1045.06, -1042.02, -1038.78, \
-1031.39, -1026.79}, {-1092.52, -1088.05, -1084.71, -1079.42, \
-1076.23, -1070.97, -1066.25, -1062.19, -1055.94, -1053.8, -1048.4, \
-1043.88, -1040.7, -1037.45, -1029.28, -1026.02}, {-1090.27, \
-1088.19, -1081.68, -1078.58, -1073.89, -1069.65, -1064.56, -1061.17, \
-1054.36, -1052.02, -1046.51, -1041.92, -1038.6, -1035.64, -1027.84, \
-1024.28}, {Mean[{}], -1084.31, -1080.94, -1076.38, -1072.75, \
-1068.46, -1063.21, -1060.06, -1053.12, -1050.63, -1045.01, -1040.35, \
-1036.84, -1034.13, -1027.63, -1023.53}, {Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}], -1079.73, -1075.39, -1072.06, -1067.47, -1062.15, \
-1058.93, -1052.32, -1049.62, -1043.91, -1039., -1035.96, -1033.12, \
-1027.7, Mean[{}]}, {Mean[{}], Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}], -1074.72, -1070.22, -1066.32, -1060.89, -1057.42, \
-1051.45, -1048.91, -1043.25, -1038.04, -1035.38, -1033.22, Mean[{}], 
  Mean[{}]}} *)
```

I am ok with the empty means, as I replace them later.

Other variables

```
minZ
(* 5162.62 *)

dz
(* 1000. *)

GridSpacingDivisionZ
(* 15 *)

minX
(* 4032 *)

dz
(* 1000. *)
```

Comment: You want the mean "height" (3rd coord.) in each rectangular bin (in a 2D array corresponding to the bins)?  (Sometimes a *description* of the objective is helpful and encouraging to others.)

Comment: A working MWE will also encourage others.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I mean "height" (3rd coord.) in each rectangular bin (in a 2D array corresponding to the bins).  Does MWE mean - Mathematica Working Example?

Comment: MWE is net-speak for "minimal working example."  Sorry for the jargon. Anyway, I came up with something without it.  But with the missing parameters, it's impossible to know the scale of the answer.  Sometimes such details affects the choice of strategy.

Comment: Hi Michael, I appreciate your advice.  I've added a numerical example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a million points processed in half a second:

```
SeedRandom[0];  (* updated for reproducibility *)
xyCoordinateCentreCircle = RandomReal[1, {1*^6, 3}];

Map[
  Mean[#[[All, -1]]] &,
  BinLists[xyCoordinateCentreCircle, {0, 1, 1/10}, {0, 1, 1/10}, {0, 1, 1}],
  {3}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*
  {0.513721,
   {{{0.506174}, {0.497757},..., {0.50284}},
    {{0.501131}, {0.497317},..., {0.501209}},
    ...,
    {{0.496007}, {0.503033},..., {0.500413}}}
*)
```

---

And a procedural method that's a bit faster (*updated* to handle zero bin counts):

```
With[{totalscounts = Compile[{{points, _Real, 2}},
    Module[{totals, counts, i1, i2},
     totals = Table[0., {10}, {10}];
     counts = Table[0., {10}, {10}];
     Do[
      i1 = 1 + Floor[p[[1]]/0.1];
      i2 = 1 + Floor[p[[2]]/0.1];
      totals[[i1, i2]] += p[[3]];
      counts[[i1, i2]] += 1.,
      {p, points}];
     {totals, counts}
     ],
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]},
 bl = Quiet[Divide @@ totalscounts[#], Divide::indet] &
 ];

bl[xyCoordinateCentreCircle] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.401225, {{0.506174,...}}  *)
```

(Note: The braces can be removed from the first method, too; or added in here.)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think I am very close with the above.   Please can you take another look with the numerical example I added just now.  I need output dimensions of Dimensions[gridmean] ={15, 16}.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorted now ---  although slightly different results. GridMeanOld - GridMeanNew =  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0., 0., 0., 0.109692, 0., 0., 0., 0.1213, 0., 0, 0, 0}, \
{0, 0, 0, 0.675241, 0., 0., 0., 0.0486794, 0., 0., 0., 0.0379739, 0., \
0., 0., 0}, {0, 0, 0., 0.220785, 0., 0., 0., 0.0199794, 0., 0., 0., \
0.0387975, 0., 0., 0., 0.}  Is this just numerical error with the different methods?

Comment: For rounding error for `n` points, one would expect `GridMeanOld - GridMeanNew)/GridMeanOld` be within an order of magnitude of `Sqrt[n] * 10^-16`.  Your errors seem a little large based on the snippet of data in the question.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you did.  If the boundaries of the grid shifted, then a point on the old boundary might find itself in a new grid cell.  That would change the means of two cells.  The errors do seem to be in adjacent cells, so maybe that's the explanation.