# Switching from AppendTo to Speed up

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, performance-tuning

I'm trying to speed up my Code, but I'm facing problems with changing the  `AppendTo` section in my code with something "Faster". I've read through some other examples that explain the use of `Reap`and `Sow`. 
[Understanding Sow and Reap documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181597/understanding-sow-and-reap-documentation/181603)
  [Writing Faster Mathematica Code - Sow and Reap?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114334/writing-faster-mathematica-code-sow-and-reap?rq=1)
  https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/

I can't figure out how to apply the Solutions given in the links for my problem.

```
n = 20;
dz = 1000/n;
RollLM[l_, EM_, Ixx_, p_] := {{1, l, Power[l, 2] / (2 EM Ixx), 
Power[l, 3] / (6 EM Ixx), p Power[l, 4] / (24 EM Ixx)}, {0, 1, l / (EM 
Ixx), Power[l, 2] / (2 EM Ixx), p Power[l, 3] / (6 EM Ixx)}, {0, 0, 1, 
l , p Power[l, 2] / 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1, p l}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
BearLM[d_, c_] := {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, d, 1, 0, 0}, 
{-c, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
pBF = Function[z, Piecewise[{{989000/500, 250 <= z <= 750}}]];

Vec1A = {vA, PhiA, 0, 0, 1};
Vec2A = BearLM[810000, 850000].Vec1A;
VecAList = {Vec2A};
Do[ AppendTo[VecAList, RollLM[dz, 210000, 262440000 Pi, pBF[(i- 
0.5)dz]] .VecAList[[i]]], {i, n}];
Vec3A = BearLM[810000, 850000].Last[VecAList];
SolA = Solve[{Vec3A[[3]] == 0, Vec3A[[4]] == 0},{vA,PhiA}] 
[[1]];
```

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `vA`, `RF`, `B`,`PhiA` meant to be numerical values? Then please define them _first_. That will speed up already quite a lot.

Comment: I changed `a`, `b`, `RF` and `B` to the numerical values. I justed overlocked to change them in the first place. But `PhiA` and `vA` will be later one solved in the Code.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[LeafCount /@ VecAList]` tells me that this is not a good idea. Better numericise `PhiA` and `vA` and use a numerical linear solver instead.

Comment: I've added the example so it is better understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like `AppendTo` has much overhead in this case.

```
n = 20;
dz = 1000/n;
RollLM[l_, EM_, Ixx_, p_] := {{1, l, Power[l, 2] / (2 EM Ixx), Power[l, 3] / (6 EM Ixx), p Power[l, 4] / (24 EM Ixx)}, {0, 1, l / (EM Ixx), Power[l, 2] / (2 EM Ixx), p Power[l, 3] / (6 EM Ixx)}, {0, 0, 1, l , p Power[l, 2] / 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1, p l}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
BearLM[d_, c_] := {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, d, 1, 0, 0}, {-c, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
pBF = Function[z, Piecewise[{{989000/500, 250 <= z <= 750}}]];

Vec1A = {vA, PhiA, 0, 0, 1};
Vec2A = BearLM[810000, 850000].Vec1A;


VecAList = {Vec2A};
Timing[Do[AppendTo[VecAList, RollLM[dz, 210000, 262440000 Pi, 
     pBF[(i - 0.5) dz]].VecAList[[i]]], {i, n}]]
```

> {0.03125, Null}

```
original = VecAList;

VecAList = {Vec2A};
Timing[Do[VecAList = {VecAList, RollLM[dz, 210000, 262440000 Pi,
     pBF[(i - 0.5) dz]].Last[VecAList]}, {i, n}]]
```

> {0.03125, Null}

```
VecAList = Partition[Flatten[VecAList], 5];
original == VecAList
```

> True

Comment: So you are suggesting that the actuall solving is the factor that costs a lot of time?

Comment: I guess so.  The second version does not use `AppendTo` and the timing is the same.

Comment: So is there a better way to solve this system with Symbolic variables and also the `n` variable  witch in this case is 20 can be 250 and then it's getting pretty slow.

Comment: That's kind of a different question.

Comment: @CR36 The solving takes a significant amount of time, but the dominant factor seems to be `RollLM[..].VecAList[[i]]`, as Henrik hinted at.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace the `AppendTo` loop with

```
u = Vec2A;
VecAList = Table[
   u = RollLM[dz, 210000, 262440000 Pi, pBF[(i - 0.5) dz]].u,
   {i, 1, n}];
```

However, this does not speed up anything as the computations are performed symbolically and this `LeafCount[VecAList[[i]]` grows exponentially with `i` (and thus `LeafCount[VecAList]` grows exponentially with `n`).

Comment: So is there something you can recomend?

Comment: That's kind of a different question.

Comment: "[K]ind of" in the sense of "very much". Would be best to scrap this question and start afresh.

Comment: I just meant to cite @ChrisDegnen... ;)